# Adding wildcards or Regex to AddSearch Search UI filters

Tags: filter, filtering, addsearch, searchui

I'm using AddSearch Search UI (https://github.com/AddSearch/search-ui). I'm trying to implement custom filters.

While I can filter on categories like in the below code, I want to be able to pass in custom regex to match things like .pdf or to dynamically check if the category begins with 0x, 1x, 2x, etc. However, I have not found any documentation or use cases on the internet on how to implement something like this.

The current code I have that works (without custom filtering) is:

```
  searchui.filters({
    containerId: 'radio-filters-container',
    type: AddSearchUI.FILTER_TYPE.RADIO_GROUP,
    options: {
      nofilter: {
        label: 'All results'
      },
      blog: {
        label: 'US',
        filter: {"category": "1xunited-states"}
      },
    }
  });
```

So far I have tried the below filtering techniques to get custom filtering to work, but nothing works.

```
      blog: {
        label: 'US',
        filter: {"category": {"$regex": "\\d+x.*\\.pdf"}}
      }

   blog: {
        label: 'US',
        filter: {"category": {"$contains": ".pdf"}}
      },

     blog: {
        label: 'US',
        filter: {"category": {"wildcard": "united-states"}}
      },
```

Really would appreciate any insight!